# how to run ios Jenkins Job which is setup on Linux Server?

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration

Is there any way to run ios Jenkins Job in Linux Server?
I Know that by creating new Jenkins slave node on ios Machine. Apart from this is there any way to achieve this.Kindly let me know is this possible in linux Environment?

--

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "ios job" uses AIR or some other SDK that can run compilation on Linux, then yes.

If your "ios job" is an XCode build, then no.

Comment: can i use the same setup for Android Projects with out any new node?

Comment: @AnilYadav Yes, there is no need for a new node just for a new project. The reasons for a different node are: 1) To get more processing power. 2) To get a different host OS/Environment